# How to check if there's a certain layer at a given point

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, layer, spawn

In my game I'm making an enemy that can spawn other enemies, and it works, but when the enemy is close to a wall there's a chance that it will spawn enemies *on/on the other side* of the wall, and I don't want that.

I wanted to check if the point (found with coordinates) where the enemy should spawn has the layer "floor" or else, so that it could actually spawn it or find another point and check again.

I tried Raycasts but I can't manage to make it work.

It's a 2D game.

Thanks

Comment: A point doesn't have a layer, objects have. If you want to check if at a certain position there would be certain colliders you do not want to shoot a cast into a certain direction but rather use e.g. [`Physics2D.OverlapCircle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) to check if a collider falls within a certain radius around your target point. Use a layer mask to only consider the layers you are looking for

Comment: Note though that just because you don't hit a wall at the point where you want to spawn doesn't prevent that point from being behind a wall! So as a second check I would use a `CircleCast` from spawner to target point and check if we hit a wall there. In that case you can either decide to abort the spawn and take another position or move the spawn point towards the spawner until it is not in the wall anymore

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, what I was trying to say with "a point has a layer" is that I have a tilemap, and the tiles of the floor have their own layer. I think now my question is much more understandable. I'd like to use your idea but I don't use colliders for the floor, and adding them seems really tiring.

Comment: @ƦØϻȜФ Couldn't you use something like https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetTile.html to check what tile is at the position?